# How Do I grab values from multiple object in a JSON format and store them in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects in a JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "word": "turkey"
  },
  {
    "word": "tiger"
  },
  {
    "word": "horse"
  },
  {
    "word": "pig"
  },
  {
    "word": "dog"
  },
  {
    "word": "cat"
  }
]
```

I want to extract the value for each "word" key and store it into an array like so:

```
let wordsArray = ["turkey", "tiger", "horse", "pig", "dog", "cat"];
```

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+property+values+from+array+of+object) of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](/q/19590865/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the value of the `word` property:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "word": "turkey"
  },
  {
    "word": "tiger"
  },
  {
    "word": "horse"
  },
  {
    "word": "pig"
  },
  {
    "word": "dog"
  },
  {
    "word": "cat"
  }
]

const res = arr.map(e => e.word);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=it) the values:

```js
console.log([
  {
    "word": "turkey"
  },
  {
    "word": "tiger"
  },
  {
    "word": "horse"
  },
  {
    "word": "pig"
  },
  {
    "word": "dog"
  },
  {
    "word": "cat"
  }
].map( ({word}) => word ))
```